# On change attribut is not initialised in thymeleaf

Tags: javascript, spring, thymeleaf

I have the following problem with javascript integrated into thymeleaf template.
I have the following table with different input fields which are filled up with data from a model.
Furthermore i have for each of this input field a hidden additional input field.
Idea is that when I change not hidden input tag, the hidden ones will receive the new value

```
                        <tr th:each=" item : ${products}">
                            <td>
                                <input class="form-control" type="text" th:value="${item.product.name}" id="productName" name="productName" />
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input class="form-control" type="text" th:value="${{item.product.price}}" id="productPrice" name="productPrice" />
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                 <input class="form-control" type="text" th:onchange="substituteOnClick()" th:value="${item.quantity}" id="quantityItem" name="quantityItem" />
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input class="form-control" type="text" th:value="${item.MinQuantity}" th:onchange="substituteOnClick()" id="minquantityItem" name="minquantityItem" />
                            </td>

                            <td>
                                <form th:action="@{/deleteWarehouseItem/{id_del}/(id_del=${item.id})}" method="post" role="form" class="ui form">
                                <button type="submit" class="ui form" name = "itemDel" th:value="${item.id}">Löschen</button>
                                </form>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                            <form class="ui form" method="post" th:action="@{/updateItem}" >
                                <input type="hidden" name="productName_mvc" id="productName_mvc" value="0" th:value="${item.product.name}"/>
                                <input type="hidden" name="productPrice_mvc" id="productPrice_mvc" value="0" th:value="${{item.product.price}}"/>
                                <input type="hidden" name="quantityItem_mvc" id="quantityItem_mvc" value="0" th:value="${item.quantity}"/>
                                <input name="minquantityItem_mvc" id="minquantityItem_mvc" value="0" />
                                <input type="hidden" name="inventoryIdentifier_mvc" id="inventoryIdentifier_mvc" th:value="${item.id}"/>
                                <button type="submit" class="ui labeled icon button" name = "updateItem" th:text="#{management.updateItem}">


                                </button>
                            </form>
                            </td>

                        </tr>
```

Here is my javascript file

```
function substituteOnClick() {
    var pN=document.getElementById("productName").value;
    var pP=document.getElementById("productPrice").value;
    var qI=document.getElementById("quantityItem").value;
    var MqI=document.getElementById("minquantityItem").value;

    document.getElementById("productName_mvc").value=pN;
    document.getElementById("productPrice_mvc").value=pP;
    document.getElementById("quantityItem_mvc").value=qI;
    document.getElementById("minquantityItem_mvc").value=MqI;


}
```

As you see my problem is that for each row I need 2 buttons for different actions, since that I decided that It would be useful just to change values of hidden inputs. It is possible because I use hidden inputs only if I need to update an object and it happens mainly on change event. But my problem is that even if I write anything new in not hidden inputs, it does not influence my hidden ones. I have cheked it by not hidding one of them.
How is it possible to change values in other inputs by changing them firstly in other ones.
Best wishes

Answer (score 0):

first of all, you need to remove these extra brackets from this line

```
 <input class="form-control" type="text" th:value="${{item.product.price}}" id="productPrice" name="productPrice" />
```

and then in your javascript use console.log() to check whether on onchange event its fetching the change value or not like

```
console.log("In js function");
console.log(qI);
```

if you are not getting these values then Instead of onchange event add a button for each input or for all input use a single button inside form and then use the onClick function or onsubmit like this:

```
   <form onsubmit="return substituteOnClick()">
   <td>
       <input class="form-control" type="text" th:value="${item.product.name}" id="productName" name="productName" />
   </td>
   <td>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" th:value="${item.product.price}" id="productPrice" name="productPrice" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input class="form-control" type="text"  th:value="${item.quantity}" id="quantityItem" name="quantityItem" />
     </td>
     <td>
          <input class="form-control" type="text" th:value="${item.MinQuantity}" id="minquantityItem" name="minquantityItem" />
     </td>
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

Let me know if this helps